# BigInteger not increasing?

Tags: java

For some reason my `val` variable isn't increasing within the while-loop. Any reason as to why it's not doing so? `val.add(BigInteger.ONE);`

```
import java.math.*;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    /* Variables */
    BigInteger PQ = new BigInteger("17");
    BigInteger E = new BigInteger("7");

    BigInteger val = new BigInteger("2");

    /* Find the PRIME factors of PQ */
    while (PQ.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) == 1) { // while the first value is greater
        if (PQ.mod(val).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
            System.out.print(val + "  ");
        } else {
            val.add(BigInteger.ONE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although [`BigInteger.compareTo(BigInteger val)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#compareTo-java.math.BigInteger-) explicitly lists return value as *"-1, 0 or 1"*, it is better to code to the more general contract inherited from `Comparable` which says *"a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer"*, so you should write `a.compareTo(b) > 0` instead of `a.compareTo(b) == 1`. It also reads better, since it means `a > b`, i.e. `a.compareTo(b) OP 0` means `a OP b`, where `OP` can be `<`, `<=`, `==`, `>=`, `>`, or `!=`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`val.add(BigInteger.ONE)` returns a new value. You do not assign it to anything:

```
val = val.add(BigInteger.ONE);
```

[Class BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Comment: Wow. Didn't even realize that. Thanks!

Comment: also note: that won't be an efficient method to factor large numbers.

Comment: "Won't be efficient" could be restated as "is impractically inefficient" .....

Comment: @Dandy BigInteger like String is immutable so you can't alter it. You can only return a new value (and just like using Strings)

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the sum again.

```
BigInteger val=BigInteger.valueOf(10);
BigInteger val2=BigInteger.valueOf(20);
BigInteger val3=va1.add(val2);
```